# kubectl top command output does not match Linux free command

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I have a one a one node Kubernetes cluster and the memory usage reported by the metrics server does not seem to be the same as the memory usage shown with the `free` command

```
# kubectl top nodes
NAME          CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
<node_ip>   1631m        10%    13477Mi         43%

# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32010       10794         488          81       20727       19133
Swap:         16127        1735       14392
```

And the difference is significant ~ 3 GB.

I have also tested this on a 3 node cluster, and the issue is present there too:

```
# kubectl top nodes
NAME          CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
<node_ip1>   1254m        8%     26211Mi         84%
<node_ip2>   221m         1%     5021Mi          16%
<node_ip3>   363m         2%     8731Mi          28%
<node_ip4>   1860m        11%    20399Mi         66%

# free -m (this is on node 1)
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32010        5787         369        1676       25853       24128
Swap:         16127           0       16127
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: Kubernetes and swap?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from understanding how both commands works.

[Free](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) - Display amount of free and used memory in the system

[Kubectl top](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#top) - Allows you to see the resource consumption for nodes or pods.

There is an [article](https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/) explaining why you might see the differences:

> Most container specific metrics are available at the cgroup filesystem
>   via `/path/to/cgroup/memory.stat`,
>   `/path/to/cgroup/memory.usage_in_bytes`,
>   `/path/to/cgroup/memory.limit_in_bytes` and others. Most of the Linux
>   tools providing system resource metrics were created before `cgroups`
>   even existed. They usually read memory metrics from the proc
>   `filesystem: /proc/meminfo`, `/proc/vmstat`, `/proc/PID/smaps` and others.

Also, the swap part (as mentioned by @uav) should trigger a red light as you must disable it in order for the kubelet to work properly. It is one of the [prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) for installing kubeadm.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I actually have the opposite problem. `kubectl top node` reports really lower mem usage than `free` and I cannot find where all the different memory is spent (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621512/cannot-find-memory-usage-in-kubernetes-cluster-node)